# VNC desktop sharing doesn't work in home network with router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, vnc

I am trying to setup **VNC desktop sharing within home network** based on a common router. 2 Linux (OpenSUSE Leap 15.1) PCs are connected via LAN, a Windows Laptop and two Android tablets (and phones, etc.) via WLAN. All by means of Belkin router. I can't get it working and ran out of google and discussions based ideas how to resolve it.

VNC is (only for the setting up process) without password, started this way:

```
x11vnc -clip 1280x800+0+0
```

It seem to run well and shows:

```
The VNC desktop is:      linux-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PORT=5900
```

EDIT: Following is turned off due to comments bellow. ~~~I tried to set my Belking router to forward IP, not sure if correctly, but it looks like this (192.168.0.105 is the Linux PC with VNC server):~~~
[image]

I *can* `PING` the VNC server computer from any device (Android tablets, another Linux PC or Windows laptop) successfully. Also, Samba file sharing is working.

In YaST (OpenSUSE's configuration tool), I set "`Allow remote administration`" and checked "`Open firewall port`" checkbox.

I used 4 different clients to avoid any trouble on this side (MultiVNC, AndroidVNC, VNC Viewer /all on Android/ and Easy Connect on Windows) setting the IP address of the Linux PC (192.168.0.105) and port `5900`.

My networking knowledge is very limited, basically to what is presented, so I am probably doing something incorrect or stupid... I don't even know how to analyze, whether is the shared desktop not reaching the router or if the router is blocking it.

Comment: Are you trying to connect locally or externally?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not obvious from my question; I am connecting only locally.

Comment: The port forwarding rule is for external access to your local machine, depending on your routers configuration you may of just opened port 5900 to the external web

Comment: "Also, Samba file sharing is working."  Great.  Can you show us that configuration which is working?  Can you provide the model number of the Belkin device you are using?  Is it possible the Belkin device is used as a Wireless Access Point (WAP), but another device is acting as a firewall from the Internet, and that device is allowing SMB (file sharing) traffic but not VNC?

Comment: @sqlTemp I had such a suspicion, but followed some troubleshooting threads, not being able to resolve it otherwise, I'll turn it off. Neither it should affect the problem negatively, I'd say

Comment: @Togam I'll try to get it. I believe I used YaST too, but I'll get the resulting config

Comment: @Oak_3260548 correct, I was just advising on a security issue which was possible to fix. your problem is going to be a firewall issue most likely, but I can not help on Linux

Comment: @TOOGAM I looked into /etc/samba/smb.conf and I don't see there anything relevant, related to network settings, except including /etc/samba/dhcp.conf. What information I should publish?

Comment: Forget about /etc/samba/smb.conf ; not expected to be relevant.  I mean, SMB typically uses TCP port 445 (or maybe 139).  What I meant to be asking for was to check the Belkin's configuration about how it handles (port forwards) these SMB-related ports.  If SMB traffic gets through the Belkin successfully, how?  Also, what is your Belkin's default gateway?  (Likely a firewalling router, possibly a "cable modem" or "DSL modem".)  My strongest hunch places the blame, for your incoming VNC traffic not working, on that gateway device's configuration.

Comment: @TOOGAM I don't see anything related to Samba in port forwarding and according to above comments this should not be relevant for local connections. In the router's firewall settings I have exeptions (always allow, all protocols) between source (the Linux PC) and destination IPs (the Androids and Win). I see there's no port range filled in, which I'd expect means "all ports".

Comment: The problem might be caused by SDDM window manager used by OpenSUSE 15.1 for KDE5, apparently it doesn't support a protocol used by vnc. I will have to try to switch to KDM.